# How to print invoice after submitting form?

Tags: javascript, php, css

Where i can find a template to customize it design. with print button..it will be very helpfull if u send me link of example, demo,

Details:
I need a template to work on, i created a form which passes values of form to another page and insert in data in database using query and echo message that record added successfully. I want a button on that page which can print it customize format.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: i think you should try first and than ask where you got stocked and than the users of stackoverflow can help you out.